# How to display author email id on cloud build logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am maintaining my source code in cloud source repository, as soon as developer push the code cloud build job is getting triggered. I want to know how to display committer email id on cloud build log/console.

Tried below method but didn't worked foe me.

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      set -x && \
      git log --format='%ae' -n 1 HEAD > /workspace/git_author.txt

- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['echo', '$(cat /workspace/git_author.txt)']
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try as below?

```
- name: ubuntu
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    EMAIL=$(cat /workspace/git_author.txt) \
    && echo $EMAIL
```

Comment: Great to hear. Please accept it as an answer :)

Comment: any idea, how i can copy author email id stored in git_author.txt to substitution variable.  Tried below but not worked.                                                                                                               EMAIL=$(cat /workspace/git_author.txt)
echo $EMAIL

Comment: I've edited my response. If you want to execute multilines, you have to proper use the yaml multiline formatting. I haven't tried but the way I edited my response should work.